# What's the different between '(a b (c)) and (list 'a 'b (list 'c))

Tags: scheme, sicp

I am working on exercise 2.57 and I have such a problem
what's the different between '(a b (c)) and (list 'a 'b (list 'c)) since they look exactly the same in the scheme interpreter?

```
1 ]=> (eq? '(a b (c)) (list 'a 'b (list 'c)))

;Value: #f

1 ]=> '(a b (c))

;Value 2: (a b (c))

1 ]=> (list 'a 'b (list 'c))

;Value 3: (a b (c))

1 ]=>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what is `(eq? (list 1) (list 1))`?

`eq?` only tests object *identity*. Two separately constructed lists are not the same list, even if their contents are the same. Use `equal?` for value equality:

```
(equal? '(a b (c)) (list 'a 'b (list 'c)))
; => #t
```